# iPhone exception handling crash my app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, exception

I am new on ios and i am following a tutorial to develop a calculator.
When i build my project it succeds, but on run time it crashes and throwa an exception:

```
 `2012-09-19 10:03:51.469 AhsanCalculator[325:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x6d59870> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pushOperand.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

My code is here if you need more detail. Tell me what you need and i will give you all the details.

Xcode = 4.3.3
5.1 iPhone simulator

Please help to solve this issue

Comment: Please show ur code .... how many views do u have in ur app ??

Comment: Some where you're using `pushOperand` .. what is this ??

Answer (score 0):

The crash occurred for you is because, in your xib you have linked/connected some wrong objects, i mean a `UITextField` to a `UITextView` or some thing like that.

When you open Xib right clicking on the files owner object, it shows some of the `IBOutlets` connected with a warning icon, delete those and connect to the right/correct one.

This will clear your crash, and works fine.

As you are new to iOS development, here are some link to learn about what to when a crash appears in the project,

Its is by [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials), here it is a 2 part tutorial [part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) and [part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2).

Comment: i am using storyboard and tell  me how can i open file owner?

Comment: check the controller object and its IBOutlets connected... some issue might be der...